# Partitioning people to friends, friends of friends and "strangers"

Tags: website-design, web-app, social-media, social

My website uses facebook data and each two users can be direct friends, have mutual friends, or none. I am trying to find the best word for this last group. "Stranger" seems kind of unfriendly. I also thought about "New Person" but that's kinda vague. The term may be used alone (without friends and Friends of friends as point of reference) so it should be able to bear the meaning all by itself. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: "Not connected".  It would be helpful to have more context if possible to understand how the terms will be used.

Comment: Thanks, but don't you think it can be mistaken with "not online". The context is that when you view a profile, I want to see their relationship to you.

Comment: "Not friends" or "Not friends yet"

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is dependent on how you are using the data, but one approach that seems to have gained some popularity recently is to use "People You Know" and "People You May Know" for friends and "friends of friends", respectively.  If you are comfortable with not having (and able to not have, within your design) a label for people with no implicit tie to the current user, this is a pretty consistent, recognizable, and "friendly" way to represent those relationships.

Comment: I have to use a term for the third group. So when you view a user's profile, I want to tell you weather that person is your friend, fof, or a stranger.